# At the end of my rope: trying to inspire someone with no healing surges left to greatness?

Tags: dnd-4e, warlord

At the end of the 7th encounter for the day, our group has basically no surges left and no option but to keep going. We have a Battle Captain Warlord:

> Battle Inspiration (16th level): When you heal an ally with your inspiring word, the ally gains a +1 power bonus to attack rolls and speed until the end of your next turn. If you have the Tactical Presence class feature, the bonus equals your Intelligence modifier.

Inspiring Word

> Minor Action
>
> Effect: The target can spend a healing surge and regain 1d6 additional hit points.
>       Level 26: 6d6 additional hit points.
>   Special: You can use this power twice per encounter, but only once per round. At 16th level, you can use this power three times per encounter.

Who gives us a +6 to attacks and speed, and healing surge+6d6 when he drops an inspiring word on us.

Given this warlord is healing a paladin that's completely out of surges (that's me!) but that I'm not yet at negative HP, what happens to me when I'm the target of this epic warlord's inspiring word?

Comment: Sad <strike>panda</strike> paladin.

Answer (score 14):

**Nothing**

Inspiring Word gives you the option of spending the healing surge and changes the amount of healing that it does. If you have no surges left to spend, you can't take that option.

If you get no healing from the Inspiring Word, there is no trigger for Battle Inspiration.

Comment: Just curious, is there a place that clarifies the additional healing is dependent on the healing surge rather than something you get in addition to the ability to spend a healing surge?  I'm fairly certain your interpretation is correct, but I would like seeing a place where it is clearcut (beyond the word "additional" as that could be read as spend a healing surge (if you have one) then gain an additional xd6)

Comment: It's actually the "and" that trips it. It links the two parts of that power together. If they were separate they would either be two effects (one for can spend a healing surge and one for regain 1d6/6d6 extra hit points) or the effect would read "The target can spend a healing surge. The target gains an additional 1d6 hit points."

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't think to look at the punctuation or similarly worded two effect powers.  Thanks.